# The difference between the "include" statement and the "#include" directive of Fortran

Tags: fortran

What is the difference between the "include" statement and the preprocessor "#include" of Fortran?

Answer (score -1):

Files included by the preprocessor #include directive can contain #defines whereas files included with the INCLUDE statement must contain only FORTRAN statements.

Comment: I don't understand your purpose with this. You have asked a duplicate, easy question, and then answered it yourself?

Comment: I think the purpose is to earn some initial rep, but OP should really have searched for a duplicate before.

Comment: The purpose is to share what I just learnt. Stackoverflow does not discourage self Q&A style because it provides this option when one is trying to ask a question.

Comment: Besides, I do not think this question is duplicate because this question assume we have known what is preprocessor and what is Fortran statement. This question is about the difference in practical use, i.e., you can not use the include statement to include a file containing preprocessors.

Comment: Anyway, I like the critical attitude of you guys, which can make the information on stackoverflow more accurate.

Comment: There is nothing automatically wrong with asking and immediately answering a question (I have done this myself).  However, those questions must still follow quality requirements and many people are more critical in assessing them in cases like this.  I agree with the duplicate closing, for what that is worth.